# annotating hexbin plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

I'm trying to create an interactive hexbin plot.
The user should be able to hoover each hex and see the annotated value.
So far i cant get the right annotations for the hexbin, but when using the same method for scatter plot it works fine.
It looks like the event for hexbin is giving me wrong indices for triggering event , how can i fix that?

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; 
np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
c = np.random.randint(1,4,size=10)

norm = plt.Normalize(1,4)
cmap = plt.cm.RdYlGn

fig =  figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# sc = ax.scatter(x,y,c=c, s=100, cmap=cmap, norm=norm) # this works
sc = ax.hexbin(x, y, C=c,picker=True) 

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):
    pos = sc.get_offsets()[ind["ind"][0]]
    annot.xy = pos
    text = "{}".format(" ".join(list(map(str,c[ind["ind"]]))))
    annot.set_text(text)

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = sc.contains(event)
        print(cont)
        print(ind)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)
show()
```

Comment: It's hard to guess what you think is wrong with the output. Can you show the wrong index?

Comment: the annotation value of each color is wrong with the hexbin, you may see green and yellow have the same value

Comment: Yep, correct. So that method is not usable for hexbins, because hexbins show *aggregated* data. E.g. it could happen that two points lie in the same bin, effectively leading to one dot on screen less than input points. What should happen in such case?

Comment: I guess you are right, thanks